# How do I make my program loop back to a certain point until a certain answer is reached

Tags: java, loops

I am in an advanced programming class and currently am working in java.  We are supposed to be designing a store.  I have reached some trouble with a part of my code.  I decided to make a store that sells different kinds of apples.  If you run my code and type in the name of an apple to find out more about it, the program will end.  I would like it to loop back to the part that asks if you would like to hear about any of the kinds of apples.  Here's what I have so far.

```
System.out.println("Bradley's Apple Store");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Today we have eight different kinds of apples.  They are Alderman apples, Akane apples, Akero apples, Alkeme apples, Ambrosia Apples, Allington Pippin apples, and American Summer Pearmain apples");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("If you would like to hear about any of the kinds of apples, type in the name of the apple.  If you would just like to purchase apples, then type purchase.");

String input = scan.nextLine();                                                     //For information on the apples
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Alderman"))
    System.out.println("An English (possible Scottish) culinary apple, thought to have originated in the 1920s. $4.00/lb");
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Akane"))
    System.out.println("One of the best early-season apples, better known in the USA than Europe, but would appeal to European tastes too. $6.00/lb");
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Akero"))
    System.out.println("An heirloom apple variety from Sweden, quite widely grown in Scandanavia, very handsome fruit. $2.00/lb");
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Alkeme"))
    System.out.println("A very attractive early Cox-style apple, slightly sharper than Cox, sometimes known as Early Windsor. $9.00/lb");
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Ambrosia"))
    System.out.println("A sweet modern apple variety from western Canada, quite similar to Golden Delicious. Discovered as a chance seedling in an orchard in British Columbia. $7.00/lb");
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Allington Pippin"))
    System.out.println("A versatile English apple, with a strong pineapple-like flavour, useful for both cooking and eating. $3.00/lb");
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("American Summer Pearmain"))
    System.out.println("An excellent early eating apple, also good for cooking. Medium size, yellow-green fruit is flushed and streaked red to purple red. Sweet, very juicy flesh. $25.00/lb");
if (input.equals("purchase"))
    System.out.println("What would you like to buy?: ");


}
```

}

Thank you for any help.

Comment: while loop should do the trick

Comment: use `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop that checks until the user enters 'exit'

```
    while (true) {
        String input = scan.nextLine(); // For information on the apples

        /*
         *  Rest of your code
         */

        // break the loop if the user enters exit
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` or `do...while` loop.

```java
boolean exitLoop = false;
do {
 String input = scan.nextLine(); //For information on the apples
 if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Alderman")) {
  System.out.println("An English (possible Scottish) culinary apple, thought to have originated in the 1920s. $4.00/lb");
  exitLoop = true;
 }
 if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Akane")) {
  System.out.println("One of the best early-season apples, better known in the USA than Europe, but would appeal to European tastes too. $6.00/lb");
  exitLoop = true;
 }
 if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Akero")) {
  System.out.println("An heirloom apple variety from Sweden, quite widely grown in Scandanavia, very handsome fruit. $2.00/lb");
  exitLoop = true;
 }
 if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Alkeme")) {
  System.out.println("A very attractive early Cox-style apple, slightly sharper than Cox, sometimes known as Early Windsor. $9.00/lb");
  exitLoop = true;
 }
 if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Ambrosia")) {
  System.out.println("A sweet modern apple variety from western Canada, quite similar to Golden Delicious. Discovered as a chance seedling in an orchard in British Columbia. $7.00/lb");
  exitLoop = true;
 }
 if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Allington Pippin")) {
  System.out.println("A versatile English apple, with a strong pineapple-like flavour, useful for both cooking and eating. $3.00/lb");
  exitLoop = true;
 }
 if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("American Summer Pearmain")) {
  System.out.println("An excellent early eating apple, also good for cooking. Medium size, yellow-green fruit is flushed and streaked red to purple red. Sweet, very juicy flesh. $25.00/lb");
  exitLoop = true;
 }
 if (input.equals("purchase")) {
  System.out.println("What would you like to buy?: ");
  exitLoop = true;
 }
}
while (!exitLoop);
```